# Stop and play video from specific point

Tags: video, html5-video

Lets say I have a video and I want to stop it at certain place and leave here a message.

For example if time was `4.282`, then I want to show message exactly at this time `4.282`.:

```
$("video").on("timeupdate",
    function(event){ if(video.currentTime == 4.282) { showMessage(); }
);
```

Hovewer `video.currentTime` updates time much rarely than it can catch the time. For example console.log(video.currentTime) will show:

```
0.15
0.66
1.12
etc
```

Also I tried with setInterval, but it's still not accurate enough.

Comment: You wont be able to have this much precision. 
You could try `setTimeout(func, 0);` with a `performance.now()` check to get a better timestamp than Date, but even then, you couldn't know when **exactly** the video did start, and some browsers doesn't support the  `performance` object... Also, `requestAnimationFrame` will fire approximately at every frame, so you could use it and check if you are near enough of the requested time, you'll at least be on the good frame. Also, I don't really get **why** you do need this precision, could you make it clearer ?

Comment: users will be able to mark and draw things on video. so it's very important to save precise time, otherwise the drawing can appear on wrong scene

Answer (score 0):

I've made it!

First you have to set timeInterval when video plays.

```
    setInterval( function() {
        var tim = video.currentTime.toFixed(2);
        var timi = tim+0.01;
        if(tim == messageTime || timi == messageTime ) { showMessage(); }
        return tim;
    }, 20);
```

This will give you video time updates much more precisely. You will get something like this:

```
1.02
1.04
1.06
etc.
```

So now it will be much easier to catch the result. Hovewer sometimes then you will play video from different time it may become:

```
1.01
1.03
```

So don't forget to add your tim variable +0.01 that will guarantee you will catch all messages.